# In page.tpl.php derive a field value from Profile

Tags: drupal, drupal-6

Prompt as in page.tpl.php derive a field value from the current user profile module. Field is called profile_first_name

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to access profile field values from `page.tpl.php` you could use [profile_load_profile()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules--profile--profile.module/function/profile_load_profile/6).

For example in your `page.tpl.php` add the following:

```
GLOBAL $user;
profile_load_profile($user);
```

Then to access the field you want (profile_first_name) you would use `$user->profile_first_name`

Comment: <?php GLOBAL $user; profile_load_profile($user); print $user->profile_first_name; ?>  Do I understand correctly? But does not work

Comment: @Siteogra there is a typo in your comment, if that is the code you used, that would explain it not working.  You forgot an underscore (_) in `profile_load_profile($user)`  Also you must be logged in and have a value for profile_first_name in your profile